# Run a Python script without installing Python

Tags: python

I have a Python script I would like to share with different people. The problem is that not everybody will be able to install Python in their computer. How can they run my Python script without converting it to an executable file?

Answer (score 1):

> How can they run my Python script without converting it to an executable file.

They can’t. Either you convert your script into a standalone executable or it is — by definition! — not standalone and needs a suitable runtime which, in this case, is the Python installation.

The canonical solution for packaging Python code as standalone executables is to use [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).